# Adding Firestore entries securely, problems with rules and authentication in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to log a user into Firestore with my React app but I want it to be secure when writing entries. I have set up a single user with email/password authentication and want to sign that in every time the page loads and adds an entry but I am getting error:

> Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but answers/userIdhere has 2

It's a simple web page with a few questions on it, we purely just want to store the answers and nothing more.

```
const auth = getAuth();
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, 'email@email.com,', 'thisisthepassword')
.then((userCredential) => {
    setAuthTrue(1);
    setUserID = userCredential.user.uid;
}).catch(() => {
    setAuthTrue(0);
});
const questionsCollectionRef = collection(db, "answers", userID);
await addDoc(questionsCollectionRef, { 
    q1: '1',
    q2: '2',
    q3: '3'
});
```

My rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write, create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "but I am getting errors" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly are the errors?

Comment: Apologies, I was meant to add the error - "Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but answers/userIdhere has 2."

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but answers/userIdhere has 2

Because of the following line of code:

```
const questionsCollectionRef = collection(db, "answers", userID);
```

Which creates a reference that points to a document that exists at `answers/$userID` and not to a collection. If you want to add a document inside the `answers` collection, then you have to remove the `userID`:

```
const questionsCollectionRef = collection(db, "answers");
```

Now you can certainly call:

```
await addDoc(questionsCollectionRef, { 
    q1: '1',
    q2: '2',
    q3: '3'
});
```

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?